# Pagination in ListView inside ListView flutter

Tags: flutter, pagination, flutter-listview, scroll-paging

I am new to Flutter development, I have a ListView.Builder which returns me some items.
The case is, I want to have another listview within the parent one which will paginate on scroll in flutter.

I searched for flutter documentation and packages, but it is said it is not recommended.
I have to implement it anyhow, can anyone suggest a solution for this?

Comment: Could you share by code or Example image etc ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [flutter listview builder inside a listview builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71719535/flutter-listview-builder-inside-a-listview-builder)